# How to generate a table in Angular6?

Tags: angular6

```js
public class TimeSheet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }        
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }  
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public WeekDays DayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
    }
 
 public class Days
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
    }

    public class DailyTask: Task
    {
        public List<Days> HoursPerDay { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a problem in binding data with table rows and columns, lets say we build a simple timesheet application in which we have Task and working hours for every task log in daily basis. For example

Task1 -> Log 2 hours on Monday and Tuesday
Task2 -> Log 5 hours on Friday

I have made some code but unable to bind columns with task, I have a table. How would I implement this in Angular6?

For json data please check attached image

[image]

```html
<table class="table" *ngIf="timeSheet.length > 0">
    <tr>
        <th>Tasks     
    </th>
    <th *ngFor="let day of weekDays">
        <span>{{ day.name }}</span>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let time of timeSheet;let t = index;">
        <td> {{t.dailyTask |json }}
            <select (change)="selectTask($event.target.value)" >
                <option *ngFor="let task of time.tasks; let x=index" value={{task.id}}>
                    {{task.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let day of time.days;let i = index;">
        <span> {{ day.hours }}
              </span>
                <input type="number" [(ngModel)] = "time.days[t].hours">            
        </td>       
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? table not generating or anything else? because your demo link shows something else.

Comment: Actually when i bind array with rows data is not binding properly with columns of a row. For example Task 1 have logged 2 hours on Monday and 5 hours on Thursday. Now problem is all row binding same data for every columns like 2 hours and 5 hours repeated with every columns of a row

Comment: Can you please use stackblitz.com for demo link so I can help you more on this.

Comment: @Hardik here is the demo linke
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhj9jn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftimesheet.component.html

Comment: if hoursPerDay is empty then show row with 0 but as you can see inside json i have hoursPerday with day wise data, but data is not showing with their respective day, it is showing on 1st columns always

Answer (score 0):

You need to create every day of week data array from server side. set 0 as a default value to hours. You'll get unexpected output if array is not valid as per the your requirement.

Please have a look on this demo [URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usm5uk?embed=1&file=src/app/timesheet.component.ts&hideExplorer=1)

eg.

```
    [{
      "employeeID": 1,
      "taskID":2,
      "hoursPerDay":[{
            "id":6,
            "name":"Monday",
            "hours":5
        },{
            "id":7,
            "name":"Tuesday",
            "hours":4
        },{
            "id":0,
            "name":"Wednesday",
            "hours":0
        },{
            "id":0,
            "name":"Thursday",
            "hours":0
        },{
            "id":0,
            "name":"Friday",
            "hours":0
        },{
            "id":0,
            "name":"Saturday",
            "hours":0
        },{
            "id":0,
            "name":"Sunday",
            "hours":0
        }]
    },
    ...
]
```